# Regarding behaviour of a branch between two independent meshes

Tags: circuit-analysis, network, mesh-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm trying to understand how a branch not part of loops affect the circuit.

---

In the following, I can apply KVL on the two loops (supermesh and the one on the right) and I get the correct answer. The two loops are independent, since one's mesh current doesn't affect the other.

But then what role does the 12.2V source plays?

[image: first figure]

---

Similar is the case for this one, the two loops are independent. Solution manual states that `KCL assures us that no current flows through either the 1Ω or 6Ω resistor.`, but I don't see how.

[image: second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But then what role does the 12.2V source plays?

None. That's the point.

> the two loops are independent.

exactly!

> KCL assures us that no current flows through either the 1Ω or 6Ω resistor., but I don't see how.

KCL says that the sum of currents into/out of each node is zero.

Look at the nodes at either end of the "1+6Ω bridge": since the current in the loop is constant, there's as much current entering the node from the loop as leaving into the loop direction, so there's zero current left to go into the bridge.

Comment: Thanks. So if I remove the 12.2 V source, it wouldn't affect the circuit dynamics, right?